# make default state for index.html without #something

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-old-router

I have this Ember router:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'hash',    
    root: Em.Route.extend({
        // EVENTS
        gotoList: Ember.Route.transitionTo('list'),

        // STATES
        list: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/list',
            connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('list');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

I would like that the route `'/'` will display the list outlet (the same as `'/list'`) but I don't want to duplicate same state like list. Can I tell somehow to the root that default state is list?

Comment: You've tagged this with backbone.js but this is about emberjs.

Comment: @shioyama: I thought that maybe backbone.js people will know how to answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps are you looking for `redirectsTo('list')` ?

```js
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash',    
  root: Em.Route.extend({
    // EVENTS

    gotoList: Ember.Route.transitionTo('list'),

    // STATES
    index: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'list'
    }),

    list: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/list',
        connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('list');
        }
    })
  })
});
```